# Jack Sparrow in the beginning of Pirates of the Caribbean 3?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, at-worlds-end

In the beginning of Pirates of the Caribbean 3, while Elizabeth Swan is rowing down the river in Singapore a shadow appears of a person running across a bridge with fireworks in the back. Now, the man/woman does the exact same running motion and gestures as Jack BUT at the time Jack's at David Jones' Locker so it couldn't be him. So my question is who was it? And why was that footage place there?

Ps: I have a theory: It was Angelica (Black Beard's daughter) that passes as Jack's impostor in POTC 4. Am I right?

Comment: Sorry this isn't anything to get excited about. It's most likely a crew member having a bit of fun while setting the props.

Comment: Could be Tia Dalma you know. Because **They go way back,thick as thieves, nigh inseperable.**

Comment: could be, but if I'd you, I wont get my hopes very high. could be some random guy, crew member just running and coincidentally it could be little similar

Comment: There is just not enough evidence to prove that is in fact Jack, but I will agree that it is a bit odd that there would be a figure in these shots at all, because clearly there are no others until we get more into the scene, so it does come off as "suspicious". But as others have said, it could be a "extra" just some guy hanging out or it could be a "scout" of either side. If it would be Jack, that would be cool, because of what it suggests about the spirit of one's soul and "fate" in POTC universe.